# iOS resizableImageWithCapInsets & @2x, @3x images

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin.ios, uiimage

I am creating a 'chat bubble' using this method, by setting the background image after calling `resizableImageWIthCapInsets`. However, for this method you need to hardcode the cap insets by pixel, but the pixel size is different for each 1x, 2x, and 3x image size. How do I get around this issue? Is there a way to know which image the device is using (the 1x, 2x, or 3x)?

Comment: 1x, 2x, and 3x shouldn't affect your cap insents

Comment: But I have the pixels values hardcoded, and since the size of the images are different, wouldn't it distort the other image sizes?

Comment: No.. it shouldn't. Because your pixels in your 2x should just be twice that of the 1x, etc.....  code your cap insets with the size of 1x pixels, you should be fine

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do it in code. Xcode has a special tool for this. Check this [link](https://krakendev.io/blog/4-xcode-asset-catalog-secrets-you-need-to-know),  in the section named "CAN I GET THOSE IMAGES FOR THESE BUTTONS, BUT LONGER?" or [here](http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.com/2015/02/image-slicing-repeatable-image-with.html). There are explanations how to use it.

If you use this you can not care if image is ready to display or which resolution you should use.